# Mounting internal directory on mounted folder with NFS

Tags: linux, mount, nfs

I am facing the following scenario:

I am mounting a folder on `/data` from `host1`.

This folder has a subdirectory: `/data/internal/config`.

I want to override this directory's mount path to be taken from `host2`.

I am using NFSv4 is it possible?

*Motivation*: I am mounting `/data` to many machines so every one of them needs to get the `/config` folder from the remote host, the `/config` folder is quite heavy so it results in a serious load on the system (size of directory * number of machines). I want to mount this folder to a closer location and override the mount of all the machines to this closer location to reduce network load.

Answer (score 0):

After you mount `/data` from `host1`, you can mount something else over `/data/internal/config` (even if this directory on `host1` is not empty):

```
mount -t nfs host2:/foo/bar/config /data/internal/config
```

Two issues:

1. You need to mount `config` *after* you mount `data`. You should unmount `config` before you unmount `data`. Use [this approach](https://askubuntu.com/q/40185/693277) or properly configure `systemd` units dependencies (if applicable).
2. You need to run/configure this additional mount on every machine.

---

The first issue can be circumvented. Instead of mounting from `host2` to `/data/internal/config`, mount to an empty directory that exists locally for sure (just create it), let it be `/mnt/config`. Then prepare a proper symlink on `host1`:

```
mv /whatever_the_share_is/internal/config /elsewhere  # just to free the name 'config'
ln -s /mnt/config /whatever_the_share_is/internal/config
```

This symlink can be broken on `host1` (or it cannot; you should know if `host1` does need this config there; place the config in `/mnt/config` on `host1` or mount it from `host2` if this is the issue, so the symlink is valid).

On every machine that mounts the share, the symlink will be resolved locally. It will point to local `/mnt/config` which either is already mounted from `host2` or will be mounted eventually. Now the mounting sequence doesn't matter.

---

The second issue stays. Maybe you expected you can reconfigure *only* `host1` to redirect all the mounting machines, so they get `config` *directly* from `host2`. I don't think this is possible (but I will upvote any sane solution that proves me wrong).